# When to use (decorate with) what and why - DefaultErpHttpDestination, DefaultHttpDestination?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

*Using java SAP Cloud SDK*

I have to use `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.outbounddeliveryv2.batch.OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatch.execute(HttpDestinationProperties destination)` to perform some updates on S/4 system. This method, `execute` takes an argument of type `HttpDestinationProperties`.

Since I need a destination, I am using below code to get destination:

```
HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyErpSystem").asHttp();
```

Since `HttpDestination` extends `HttpDestinationProperties`, we can safely pass it to `execute`. But according to [step 4 of 'Connect to OData Service on Cloud Foundry Using SAP Cloud SDK' tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-odata-service-cloud-foundry.html), the code for accessing destination looks like this:

```
ErpHttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyErpSystem").asHttp().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
```

and then they pass that destintion to the `execute` method of the service.

My question is that since `execute` methods takes an argument of type `HttpDestinationProperties`, How would I know that I have to use `DefaultErpHttpDestination`? Same thing goes for `DefaultHttpDestination`.

I have following questions -

1. When and why should I wrap the destination in `DefaultErpHttpDestination`?
2. When and why should I wrap the destination in `DefaultHttpDestination`?
3. Why should I wrap the destination in above two wrappers at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent question!

The context:

- Of course you can keep using your original approach:

  ```java
  HttpDestination destination =
    DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyErpSystem").asHttp();
  ```

  This is the recommended way for *destinations* targeting a **generic** HTTP service endpoint.
  It loads the required destination properties for HTTP connections, e.g. URL, Authentication, ...

---

- In the tutorials we are describing the integration with *S/4HANA* OData services:

  ```java
  HttpDestination destination =
    DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyErpSystem").asHttp()
      .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);
  ```

  By "decorating" the `HttpDestination` instance with *ERP* properties, we enable **additional** S/4 related HTTP request headers: `sap-client` and `sap-locale`. With the above configuration, those values are read automatically from the *destination* service - if they are set.

---

Your questions (changed order):

> "When and why should I wrap the destination in DefaultHttpDestination?"

`DestinationAccessor#getDestination` returns a generic `Destination`. In order to make sure we are dealing with HTTP (and not RFC) connections, you need to run `#asHttp` - as you already do. With the resulting `HttpDestination` instance, you can run HTTP queries like *OData* and *REST*. Depending on your use case, no additional wrapping is required.

For example, if you were about to use *BAPI* endpoints, then you'd need to run `#asRfc` instead. This method will check for different *destination* properties to make sure all required values are set.

> "When and why should I wrap the destination in DefaultErpHttpDestination?"

It is recommended to wrap the destination in `DefaultErpHttpDestination` only when you are dealing with *S/4* service endpoints and you rely on custom values for `sap-client` and `sap-locale`. The wrapping can be done at any time of your application runtime, as long as it happens before `#execute(HttpDestinationProperties)` method.

If you do not want to wrap it a second time, then you'd need to manually manage the HTTP request headers for `sap-client` and `sap-locale`.

> "Why should I wrap the destination in above two wrappers at all?"

This is the API contract. It makes sure all required *destination* properties are correctly set before even invoking the actual request. The (optional) *ERP* flavored wrapping of the destination instance was provided to make sure all *S/4* properties are automatically considered as well.