# Java SDK ignores sap-client property of Destionation on metadata request

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am using the Java SAP Cloud SDK version 3.11.0 and have the following VDM request:

```
final Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyDestination");

Try<OutbDeliveryHeader> deliveryHeaderTry = Try.of(() -> new DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service()
                    .getOutbDeliveryHeaderByKey(deliveryDocument)
                    .execute(destination.asHttp()))
                    .onFailure(e -> logger.error("Failed to read delivery header " + deliveryDocument
                            + ": " + e.getMessage(), e));
```

I need this request to be executed against the system configured in "MyDestination" with a specific SAP client. I therefore added the additional property `sap-client` with the corresponding value in my destination.

Unfortunately however, this request returns the following error:

```
Unable to fetch the metadata : Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
```

While debugging the SDK, I found that the method `getEdm` of `com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache` never adds the `sap-client` information as either a HTTP header or URL parameter to the metadata request.(Using Postman, I was able to show that the metadata request indeed needs a `sap-client`, otherwise it fails. This is the explanation why the VDM request fails in the first place.)

Now my question is whether this is intended behavior or a bug in the SDK?

I figured that using `.withHeader("sap-client","600").onRequestAndImplicitRequests()` in my VDM request fixes my problem, but if I am supposed to add this information to every VDM request, then why should I set the `sap-client` in the destination?

Or is an OData metadata request designed to be "client agnostic" and that is the reason why the `sap-client` is not added to the metadata request in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are connecting to an *S/4* OData service, the request expects additional HTTP headers. Custom values for `sap-client` and `sap-locale` can be either set manually (as you did, described in your question). Or you can use the following code:

```java
HttpDestination destination =
  DestinationAccessor.getDestination("MyDestination").asHttp()
    .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);

[...]
new DefaultOutboundDeliveryV2Service()
  .getOutbDeliveryHeaderByKey(deliveryDocument)
  .execute(destination));
```

By using this additional "decoration" step for type `HttpDestination`, the destination object is automatically provided the *S/4* flavored properties as described above. For example, the value for `sap-client` saved in your destination service will be added by default, without needing to manually invoke `.withHeader(...).onRequestAndImplicitRequests()`.

I described the context in the following SO response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59969716/9350514